# Weird segmentation fault when allocating memory in subfunction in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This is my code, which allocates space for a matrix of size specified by the parameters, and returns a pointer to said matrix:

```
int **allocateSpace(int row, int col){  
   int i;
   int **a;
   a = malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);
   for(i = 0; i < row; i ++)                                               
      a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * col);  
   return a;
}
```

The above code works as intended.

However, when I change the code to the following form I get a segmentation fault:

```
void allocateSpace(int **a, int row, int col){
    int i;
    a = malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);
    for(i = 0; i < row; i ++)
      a[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
}
```

It seems like when returning from the `allocateSpace()` function, the memory allocated was released (since I got a segmentation fault). But why? All I am doing is allocating memory for a given pointer, and it's all done in the subfunction.

To summarize my question: Why am I getting a segmentation fault in the second piece of code?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you need to pass in a pointer to a pointer to a pointer in order to assign the allocated memory:

```
void allocateSpace(int ***a, int row, int col){
    int i;
    *a = malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);
    for(i = 0; i < row; i ++)
      ( *a )[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * col);
}
```

And to call it you would need to pass the address of an `int**`:

```
int** ppData;

allocateSpace( &ppData, 10, 10 );
```

Comment: +1 you got your answer in just before me *and* put an example of how to call.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to change a pointer that is passed by value:

```
void allocateSpace(int **a, int row, int col){
  // ...
}
```

`int** a` here is passed by **value** (i.e. the pointer value is copied to the stack in order to use it as function parameter).

When you then do

```
a = malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);
```

you change only the **copy** of the pointer and once the function returns, your change is discarded.

The solution is to pass the pointer by reference, i.e.

```
void allocateSpace(int ***a, int row, int col){
//...
}
```

and change the real value by following the reference:

```
*a = malloc(sizeof(int *) * row);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you are modifying the function's parameter `a` - that is a local copy passed by value. So, if you call the function like: `allocateSpace(myptr,N,M)`, `myptr` will not be modifed - a copy local to the function will. Therefore, `myptr` contains whatever it contained before the call - possibly garbage. You would need to change the function param to: `int ***a` (oh the horror) and then put an additional `*` (dereference op) before each reference to `a` in the function body.

Compare this to the situation where you want to modify a simple int in a function - the param should be `int *` and assignments in function body should go to `*a`. Same applies here - one additional level of dereference is needed to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

In the second function int **a is passed by value (the pointer) so changes in the function dont affect the caller's function. You have to pass this value by reference.